# Jquery live rss feed?

Tags: jquery, rss

I'm trying to integrate rss items to be inserted live as they are posted into http://elektronaut.github.com/jquery.livetwitter/

Any pointers on how to do this efficiently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the solution, some sort of pooling mechanism is in order.
[Here's a demo](http://www.jquery4u.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/demo1.html) which uses [jQuery Get RSS Feed Live Reader](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-rss-feed-display-live/)

Comment: this solution is rather long and procedural, not like a normal jquery plugin at all